# Excel vlookup function given none

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have dates & names in a table1(in first image) .I want to fill names according to dates (in second image)

For example 01.04.2020 and 19.04.2020 belongs to A.  So, in the other table will be

01.04.2020 | A
That code given value #none
Vlookup(A2;Sayfa1!A:B;1;FALSE)

[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH. In vlookup, the lookup value must be found in the *leftmost* column of the lookup table.

Comment: Consider [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/). It's a good screencapping tool and you can bind a keyboard shortcut like Ctrl+Shift+P to capture and send to your clipboard for each pasting elsewhere.

Comment: @BigBen can you explain with code to İndex match function?

Comment: `=INDEX(Safya2!A:A,MATCH(A2,Safya2!B:B,0))` or something like that if I follow your screenshot correctly... and change the `,` to `;` if needed.

Comment: Thank you i got it :)